# How to add more layers to the Huggingface pretrained ALBERT model?

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to add a layer after the pretrained ALBERT model. I want to use the ALBERT pretrained model to generate tokens.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import AlbertTokenizer, TFAlbertForMaskedLM


tokenizer = AlbertTokenizer.from_pretrained('albert-base-v2')
model = TFAlbertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('albert-base-v2')
input_ids = tf.constant(tokenizer.encode("This is a test! Nice to meet you![MASK]love you"))[
    None, :]  # Batch size 1
print(input_ids)
outputs = model(input_ids)
prediction_scores = outputs[0]
outputTokens = tf.math.argmax(prediction_scores, axis=2)
outputTokens = tf.keras.backend.eval(outputTokens[0])
outputTokens = tokenizer.decode(outputTokens)
print(outputTokens)

tokenModel = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128,input_shape=input_ids.shape),
    model(),
    tf.keras.layers.Softmax()
])
tokenModel.summary()
```

Which outputs:

```
/test.py", line 19, in <module>
    model(),
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

What should be the model like? I can't add the ALBERT model as the first layer of the model in TensorFlow.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [these lines](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/cd56f3fe7eae4a53a9880e3f5e8f91877a78271c/src/transformers/models/albert/modeling_tf_albert.py#L1147-L1161)?